# WinError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, what should I use instead of select library for windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, select, winsock

I was coding a chatroom (actually a part of it is copied from a website) and I could run it on my kali machine without any problem, but in windows, I got the Error "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and I think I should not use the select library for this script(I searched about it), but... I don't know what exactly should I do?? I mean what library should I use instead ??

here's my code(the client side, I think the problem is for the client part):

```
    def banner():
    print("██████╗ ██╗████████╗ ██████╗██╗  ██╗     ██╗  ██╗")
    print("██╔══██╗██║╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝██║  ██║     ╚██╗██╔╝")
    print("██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║     ███████║█████╗╚███╔╝ ")
    print("██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║     ██╔══██║╚════╝██╔██╗ ")
    print("██████╔╝██║   ██║   ╚██████╗██║  ██║     ██╔╝ ██╗")
    print("╚═════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝    ╚═════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝     ╚═╝  ╚═╝")




def usage():
    print('''"[removeAll]password" => remove all of the recent messages from server and all of the clients''')
    print('''"[removeAll]" => remove all of the recent messages for the clients''')
    print('''"[CountMessages]password" => get the number of the messages in history''')




banner()
usage()
 
import socket  
import select  
import sys  
import pyttsx3
import os
import time




server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
if len(sys.argv) != 3:  
    print ("Correct usage: script, IP address, port number") 
    exit()  
IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])  
Port = int(sys.argv[2])  
server.connect((IP_address, Port))  
  
while True:  
   
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]  
  
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])  
  
    for socks in read_sockets+[sys.stdin]:  
        if socks == server:  
            message = socks.recv(2048)


            print (message.decode())
        else:  
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            if "[removeAll]" in message:
                os.system("clear")
                banner()
                usage()
                print('\n\n[+] old messages were removed\n\n')
            server.send(message.encode())
            sys.stdout.write("\n<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.flush()  
server.close()
```

Comment: select can't be used with file handles in windows, only sockets.  So `sys.stdin` can't be in the sockets list.

Comment: I know but... what should I do instead??